# HttpWebRequest Auth Post Request in c#

Tags: c#

i'am using burp suit to check the requests and i m trying to convertthis to  c# code

```
POST /sso HTTP/1.1
Host: account.ankama.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Referer: http://www.dofus.com/fr
Cookie: LANG=fr; _ga=GA1.1.1197518596.1489526959; SID=452EDCF3C4BD32057F9F08254BE40001
Connection: close
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 102

action=login&from=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dofus.com%2Ffr&login=user123&password=password1232F&remember=1
```

So i tried to :

```
        HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://account.ankama.com/sso?action=login&from=https%3A%2F%2Faccount.ankama.com%2Ffr%2Fsecurite%2Fmode-restreint%3Ff%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Faccount.ankama.com%2Ffr%2Fidentification%3Ff%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Faccount.ankama.com%2Ffr%2Fcompte%2Finformations&login=user111&password=password1472F");
        Request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        Request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
        Request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0";
        Request.Host = "account.ankama.com";         
        Request.Referer = "https://account.ankama.com/fr/votre-compte/profil";
        Request.Method = "POST";
        Request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        Request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        //quest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user123", "passowrd123");
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("odm.html");
                writer.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());
                writer.Close();
                reader.Close();
                Console.WriteLine("Done");
            }

        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```

in the file odm.html I m checking if the html code contain "My account" that shown when the user is actually logged in .
but this doesnt seems to be working for some reasons that i still don't know .
i made some research to about HTTP status code but in my brup suit after trying to login in with an actual exisiting account and a none valid account it gives the same http code  302 with a different Content Length .

**EDIT:**
the issue is i don't find 'my account' in the html file , i only find the page where the user is going to login

Comment: It appears you have sensitive information present your c# query string. I suggest to remove them.

Comment: Did you try by adding the cookies to your request? Usually I take the approach of having everything then removing the pieces that appear useless one by one.

Comment: i tried in my burp suit to send the reqeust without them and it works , so they arent really important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to send request body in query string, you are setting the request method as `POST` but you are not sending the body. The request url should be:

```
https://account.ankama.com/sso
```

And you need to set request body before sending the request:

```
var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("action=login&from=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dofus.com%2Ffr&login=user123&password=password1232F&remember=1");
request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

Comment: touhght about ! , i'll try it now

Comment: it works Sir ! except that m getting an exception " i cannot set the request.ContentLength property while reading the stream

Comment: @Huster okey, I updated the code, just set the ContentLength out of the using statement it should be fine.